# Jboss 7 migration - ValidationException: Unable to find provider: HibernateValidator

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, hibernate-validator, server-migration

my work place is migrating from Jboss 6 to Jboss 7.

We use v 5.1.3 Hibernate Validator, and when we tried to deploy our web application in the Jboss 7 server, and it threw an exception.

```
09:23:56,031 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (External Management Request Threads -- 4) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("read-attribute") failed - address: ([
    ("deployment" => "ROOT.war"),
    ("subsystem" => "jaxrs"),
    ("rest-resource" => "org.apache.cxf.rs.security.oauth.services.RequestTokenService")
]): javax.validation.ValidationException: RESTEASY008520: Unable to load Validation support

Caused by: javax.validation.ValidationException: Unable to find providerclass org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidator
```

I am not overly familiar with ether Jboss and Hibernate Validator, and tried googling the issue with little success.

Answer (score -1):

Look here https://coredump.su/questions/35063076/how-can-i-disable-javaxvalidationapi-in-jboss-64. Try add this to your jboss-deployment-structure.xml:

```
<exclude-subsystems>
  <subsystem name="jaxrs"/>
</exclude-subsystems>
<exclusions>
  <module name="javaee.api"/>
  <module name="javax.validation.api"/>
  <module name="javax.faces.api"/>
  <module name="org.hibernate.validator"/>
</exclusions>
```

Maybe you have conflict with jboss modules.