# Intellij IDEA ide is not deploying war file to JBOSS 7

Tags: intellij-idea, deployment, jboss, ide, jboss-eap-7

I am migrating an application from JBOSS EAP 6 to JBOSS EAP 7.
When attempting to run the application the from the IDEA in JBOSS 6, the application is able to deploy it from the IDE.

However, when I try to do the same in JBOSS 7, the artifact keeps saying "waiting for server connection to start deployment"

When the JBOSS 7 server is running from the IDEA ide, I can access the management console, and deploy the application from web browser. And from there the application can deploy, [Though it has separate issue there.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54695336/jboss-7-migration-validationexception-unable-to-find-provider-hibernatevalid)

But I can't get it to deploy from the IDE, which is going to make debugging a problem.

Note: I am using the Intellij Idea Ultimate Edition.

Comment: Please report a bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA with the log from the run console and [idea.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085). https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-199520 can be related.

Comment: There was a port switch from 9999 to 9990 on the management interface. Maybe it needs to be reconfigured to use the new port.